# Vertically Align elements in a div row

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML looks like this and I am trying to vertically align all the header elements in middle. Everything works fine except clock `div`.

```js
$(function(){
   startTime();
   positionDiv();
   $( "#innerDiv" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
     $("#innerDiv").hide();
    }else if(e.keyCode == 13) {
     $("#innerDiv").show();
    }
  });

  function startTime() {
      var today=new Date();
      var h=today.getHours();
      var m=today.getMinutes();
      var s=today.getSeconds();
      m = checkTime(m);
      s = checkTime(s);
      document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = h+":"+m+":"+s;
      var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
  }

  function checkTime(i) {
      if (i<10) {i = "0" + i}; 
      return i;
  }

  function positionDiv () {
   console.log('Ready to position inner div');
   var innerDiv = document.getElementById("innerDiv");
   if (document.getElementById('centerCheckbox').checked) {
    console.log('Setting the position to center');
    innerDiv.className = "box";
    $('#boxText').text("Center")
   } else if(document.getElementById('lrCheckbox').checked) {
    console.log('Setting the position to lower right corner');
    innerDiv.className = "lowerRightCorner";
    $('#boxText').text("Lower Right Corner")
   }
  }
```

```css
html, body {
   height: 100%;
  }
  body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   color: #000;
   background-color: #fff;
  }
  html {
   overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  .head, .foot, .middle {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
  }
  .middle {
   top: 100px;
   bottom: 50px;
   height: 400px;
   background-color: #ffd;
  }
  .head {
   height: 100px;
   top: 0;
   background-color: #000;
   color: #fff;
   display: table;
  }
  .foot {
   height: 50px;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: #000;
  }
  .middle p {
   border: 1px solid #00f;
   margin: 0;

  }

  .box {
   position:fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width:30em;
      height:18em;
      margin-top: -9em; 
      margin-left: -15em;
      border: 2px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #f3f3f3;
  }

  .lowerRightCorner {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 50px;
      right: 0;
      width:30em;
      height:18em;
      border: 2px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #f3f3f3;
    }

  #clock {
   float: right;
  }

  .position {
   float: left;
  }

  .helpText {
   margin-left: 40%;
  }

  .container {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Vertica Web</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  
 </script>

</head>
<style type="text/css">
  

</style>
<body>
 <div class="head">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="position">
   <span>Position: </span>
   <input type="radio" name="position" value="center" id="centerCheckbox" onclick="positionDiv()" checked>Center
   <input type="radio" name="position" value="lowerRight" id="lrCheckbox" onclick="positionDiv()" >Lower Right
  </div>
  <div class="helpText">Press Esc key to hide the window. Enter to show it again.</div>
  <div id="clock"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="middle">
  <div id="innerDiv">
   <span id="boxText"></span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="foot">footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess, .helpText margin-left is creating problem

Comment: @Etash Then how can keep `helpText` in the middle.

Comment: @Etash Removing it did not help it.

Comment: Set width for position and clock in % and then set width for .helptext and align it to center

Comment: Try putting your clock element before your helpText element. Floating takes precedence over elements after it, not before.